# Using the letters a,h,i,o,p,s,t, create an exclamatory sentence decrying the poor quality of an electronic cash register

Tags: word, wordplay

Using the letters

> a,h,i,o,p,s,t

create an exclamatory sentence decrying the poor quality of an electronic cash register. Letters can be used more than once. If people have trouble, I will add hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps

> *This POS is a p.o.s.!*
>   (POS is short for "Point-of-Sale system", while p.o.s. is short for "piece of s**t".)

Comment: You got it!  Good job!